# Kentico clone and customize cms.file

Tags: kentico

Here's what I'm trying to do. When a user uploads a file, i need them to make one of three options. I'll then create a transformation to link to the file, with the option they selected determining the which icon.

I started with cloning the cms.file, and then created the new field i needed for the options. I then uploaded a file using that page type. I don't see my option list (Drop-down list) on the upload screen, or after the file has been saved.

I'm been playing with the Layout but that doesn't seem to help. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a simple page type that has a file upload field, that would solve your issue, and also you could include your extra field or fields in your new page type.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I have it working, just needs some work on the transformations!

Comment: How do i get the URL of the uploaded file so i can link to it? All i'm getting is the page that's created.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure we have enough information to debug why your custom page type might not be showing the field you added, but a possible workaround: depending on what you are basing the icon on, it may work to just use different icons based on the file type? Kentico even has a method you can use to get a file icon based on the extension:

```
<%# GetFileIcon(Eval("FileExtension")) %>
```

Otherwise, maybe you can include some more information about your custom page type such as a screen shot of the fields and of the form tab for that page type. Is the "icon" field you added simply not showing up in the form?

Comment: I've used that method, but this is different. It's always a PDF, but the pdf could be one of three types. So i'm thinking have the admin pick the type when they upload the PDF.